# Acer C7 Chromebook running 13.10 slow Performance Graphics?

Tags: 13.10, video, performance, acer

I see others are having simiar issues but I haven't found a fix. Instead of the Intel fdriver, Ubuntu showing gallium driver. Honestly, the performance is sluggish, I wasn't even sure it was Video issues to begin with but apparently so. Can anyone provide a sure fire fix? 12.04 ran perfectly. 13.10 is so much betterhank you everyone!

=(

Answer (score 0):

Hey sorry if this is to late, not sure if youve solved this or not but for anyone having trouble still the solution is to upgrade your linux kernel, however if you are running Chrubuntu, you will get an error since the new kernel is not compatible, to get around this you should look into Sea-Bios legacy boot, it essentially is GRUB and allows you to install an OS from a USB. More information can be found here ;) https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/ this is the download page for Sea-Bios, then you should look for your model chromebook.

WARNING: to use this you need to follow all directions on the page, Including disabling write protection which WILL VOID YOUR WARRANTY and you need to know your GPU model (for the Acer C7 its either 847 or 1007u)

Hope This Helps =)